# How to migrate Windows DNS to pdns

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dns-zone, powerdns

I want to migrate a Windows based DNS server (server 2008 I think) to powerdns.

What's the best way to do this. I'm familiar with pdns and linux  but don't know much about the windows part.
How do I export zones from there porperly etc.

The info I found on google wasn't helpful after all.

Comment: Perform a zone transfer.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the easiest method to export DNS zone-data from one name-sever to another is by [zone-transfer](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc782181%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

A zone-transfer (`dig -t AXFR example.com @ns.example.com`) should give you the whole zone in a standardized DNS format, also known as a Bind zone file. Then use the [PowerDNS tooling](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/migration/) to load as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a comprehensive step-by-step, but the options I can think of are:

DNSShell Powershell module: https://dnsshell.codeplex.com/

dnscmd.exe : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc772069.aspx

Zone transfers + dig

Comment: Well I don't want you to do my job. thanks for the info :)
Any suggestion what's the fastest way to get zone data in pdns's mysql db.

zone2sql sounds like the way to go